# Calling useState inside useEffect on DOM load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an app to track habits, and when a user is directed to a dashboard, I want them to immediately see their habits as pulled from a database. I have tried calling useState from within useEffect, but I know that there are problems inherent in doing so. I have tried providing a second argument to useEffect to get around this, but am still receiving an invalid hook call error.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = useState(true);
  const [habits, setHabits] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(refetch){
      fetch('/habits/getHabits', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
        body: JSON.stringify({username: 'Phil'})
      })
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const habitCards = [];
      for(let habit of data.habits){
        habitCards.push(
          <Habit 
          key={habit.habitid}
          habitname={habit.habitname}
          moneyspent={habit.moneyspent}
          lasttime={habit.lasttime} 
          />
        )
      }
      setHabits(habitCards);
    })
    .finally(() => setRefetch(false))
    }
  }, [refetch])
  return (
    <div className='dash'>
      <h1>Your habits:</h1>
      {habits}
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I modify this so that useEffect is only called when the page loads, and state is updated from within it?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be pushing JSX into state. State is for data, not markup.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code snippet you shared that would trigger any React hook issues. If you want the `useEffect` hook to run only once then use an empty dependency array. It's anti-pattern in React to store JSX in state, store the data and compute the JSX from state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your effect to run only once when the page loads, then pass an empty dependency array `[]` as the second parameter.

When you pass an empty dependency array, you're telling React that this effect does not rely on any values from props or state, and that it never needs to re-run.

```
  useEffect(() =>
  {
      fetch('/habits/getHabits', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
        body: JSON.stringify({username: 'Phil'})
      })
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const habitCards = [];
        for(let habit of data.habits){
          habitCards.push(
            <Habit 
              key={habit.habitid}
              habitname={habit.habitname}
              moneyspent={habit.moneyspent}
              lasttime={habit.lasttime} />
        )
      }
      setHabits(habitCards);
    })
  }, [])
```

In this case you would no longer need your `refetch` state variable.

You can read more about skipping effects [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).